# Generic Type Parameter Inference

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a handy collection in my middle tier which is for collections of child things that belong to a parent thing.

```
public class ChildCollection<TParent, TChild>
{
    public IEnumerable<TChild> GetChildren();
    etc.
}
```

In the interface, I've got a handy grid that can display the contents of a ChildCollection<TParent,TChild> and let users do work on it.

```
public abstract class ChildCollectionGrid<TCollection, TParent, TChild> : MyGridControl
    where TCollection : ChildCollection<TParent, TChild>
{
    public abstract TCollection Collection;
    etc.
}
```

Inheriting this class to make a grid to work with the Waffles on a Widget ends up looking like this.

```
public class WidgetWafflesGrid : ChildCollectionGrid<WidgetWafflesCollection, Widget, Waffle>
```

This is a little redundant.  A WidgetWaffleCollection *is* a ChildCollection<Widget,Waffle>.  With that first generic type argument specified, the class won't compile unless you specify exactly those two others.

Is there a prettier way to accomplish this where the compiler could infer those other two types?  I know I'm being finicky but ideally I would like to have the class declaration look like:

```
public class WidgetWafflesGrid : ChildCollectionGrid<WidgetWafflesCollection>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not. Generic parameter inference works only on methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why derive from your collection? Just keep it like:

```
public abstract class ChildCollectionGrid<TParent, TChild> : MyGridControl
{
    public abstract ChildCollection<TParent, TChild> Collection;
    etc.
}

public class WidgetWafflesGrid : ChildCollectionGrid<Widget, Waffle>
{  
}
```

Comment: Actually that was my original design! Obviously I've left out a lot of details, but suffice to say my concrete collection classes have lots of specific goodies and it felt less than ideal to always be casting the Collection property.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to handle inheritance in collections with Generics is using the `Collection<TCollection,TChild> : where TCollection : Collection<TCollection,TChild> { }` pattern.

Here is an example with a concrete class

```
public abstract class Collection<TCollection, TChild>
    where TCollection : Collection<TCollection, TChild>, new()
{
    protected Collection()
    {
        List=new List<TChild>();
    }
    protected List<TChild> List { get; set; }

    public TCollection Where(Func<TChild, bool> predicate)
    {
        var result=new TCollection();
        result.List.AddRange(List.Where(predicate));
        return result;
    }

    public void Add(TChild item) { List.Add(item); }
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TChild> collection) { List.AddRange(collection); }
}

public class Waffle
{
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class WafflesCollection : Collection<WafflesCollection, Waffle>
{
    public WafflesCollection BurnedWaffles
    {
        get
        {
            return Where((w) => w.Temperature>108);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WafflesCollection waffles=new WafflesCollection();

        // Count = 3
        waffles.Add(new Waffle() { Temperature=100 });
        waffles.Add(new Waffle() { Temperature=120 });
        waffles.Add(new Waffle() { Temperature=105 });

        var burned=waffles.BurnedWaffles;
        // Count = 1
    }
}
```